# argparse module not working in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to get the argparse module working in Python. My problem is that on a fresh install, I get the following:

```
File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
import argparse
File "/home/jon/Pythons/realmine/argparse.py", line 3, in <module>
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Short sample app')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'
```

`test.py` is:

```
import argparse
```

Clearly, I'm missing something. Can anyone help?

Comment: How can `test.py` contain a single line when the error references line 3?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Usually this symptom is the result of shadowing a builtin module with one of your own.  And from the error message:

```
File "/home/jon/Pythons/realmine/argparse.py", line 3, in <module>
```

it looks like you have your own module argparse.py, which is causing the problem, because it's the one which test.py is trying to import, and which lacks ArgumentParser.  Rename your argparse.py to something else (and remove any .py[c/o] files).

Comment: Well I feel retarded. The file I was using was called argparse.py. Thank you much :)

Comment: interestingly, I made exactly the same bozo move and this SO thread solved my problem in seconds.

Comment: Haha, who do you tell that? Nice to see I’m not the only moron around. :D

Comment: Again and again faced with my same stupid mistake >.<

Thanks, @DSM

Comment: Its interesting how many people are doing the same sandbox naming

Comment: add me to this list of morons ;)

Comment: he he i did the same and needed to come stackoverflow now the feeling is the same. lol

Comment: did the same mistake, lmao by seeing the above comments :0

Comment: HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAAHAHAHAHA IM DONE

Comment: Given how common this mistake is maybe it's the implicit nature of import that's the issue? hmmmm.