# Object has no attribute using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm following [this tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) trying to implement `argparse` into a `python` script I'm writing.

When I run this snippet of code from the tutorial I receive the following error:

```
[05:51 PM] user Scripts> cat argparse.py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()



[05:51 PM] user Scripts> python3 argparse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argparse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import argparse
  File "/home/brian/Documents/Scripts/argparse.py", line 2, in <module>
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ArgumentParser'
```

I'm running `Python 3.3.2` and have installed `argparse 1.2.1` using `easy_install` so I know it's on the system but I cannot determine what is causing the error.

Note: I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605851/python-newbie-working-with-argparse) and it is not related.

Comment: You don't need the easy_install version with 3.3.2 (or 2.7).  It comes  with those newer Pythons.

Comment: That is good to know.  Im on a CentOS box so I had to do the `altinstall` in order not to break `yum`, the article I was following just had me do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the error message I am guessing your script is trying to import not from argparse package but from local `/home/brian/Documents/Scripts/argparse.py` module. Rename your file and try again.

Comment: Thank you, I should have known better than to name the script argparse.py, renaming it worked as expected.  I'll mark this as correct as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Also delete any `argparse.py*` remaining files like `argparse.pyc`